# Square bracket trouble in regex

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble with a regex. I basically want to remove everything but brackets, including 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,+,-,*,/

An example would be

```
(9*[3*{[(3+3)/5]*7}]) # should give the answer ([{[()]}])
```

My current regex is

```
[0123456789+-\\*/] # and it gives the answer ({()]}])
```

That's giving me the correct answer except `[` is matching the regex, and I don't want it too. However `]` does not match so I am confused.

Comment: "Everything but brackets", that means you want to use a negative character class [`[^][(){}]`](https://regex101.com/r/q3i9xy/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest solution provided by [@HamZa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709115/square-bracket-trouble-in-regex/41709178#comment70613689_41709115) in the comments [using the negative char `^`](https://regex101.com/r/q3i9xy/1)

```
[^][(){}]
```

Another solution is to move the `-` char to the start or the end of the regex, as in the current position is being treated a range character just like in `A-Za-z`

```
[0123456789+\\*/-]
```

Check it in http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=96675

Comment: `-` can also be the at the beginning of character class.

Answer (score 1):

Use the posix expression for "any non bracket":

```
[^\p{Ps}\p{Pe}]
```

and replace it with blank

- `\p{Ps}` or `\p{Open_Punctuation}`: any kind of opening bracket.
- `\p{Pe}` or `\p{Close_Punctuation}`: any kind of closing bracket.